# WinSCP: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. Connection failed

Tags: winscp

I'm supposed to access a server, but when I use WinSCP with FTP protocol to log in, I just get a warning that

> The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
>   Connection failed.

I really have very little experience with working remotely on servers, or even logging into them. What are my alternatives?

Comment: I have found that FileZilla works well for Windows. Here is the link: http://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 6):

This is the `WSANO_DATA`. error Quoting Microsoft documentation:

> The usual example for this is a host name-to-address translation attempt ... which uses the DNS (Domain Name Server). An MX record is returned but no A record—indicating the host itself exists, but is not directly reachable.

*(This can possibly happen for newly registered domain names that are no fully setup yet.)*

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2#WSANO_DATA or
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_name_no_data

It could have been a temporary issue. Also make sure you specify your hostname without the leading `ftp://` (though the latest version of WinSCP will strip it automatically).

Answer (score 2):

You can find a very nice discussion on the same issue with WinSCP [here](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6638)

You can also try [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) or [Putty](http://www.putty.org/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are typing your address like ftp://ftp.domain.com or things like that, remove the first part and just keep ftp.domain.com in your host address box.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), which comes with a number of tools including a `ssh` client and a secure copy tool like WinSCP called `pscp`.  Possibly even more valuable is the `psftp` client, which allows secure ftp to remote servers.  PuTTY can be run from a usb drive, making it easy to carry with you to any computer, allowing you to remote into your server from all over the world.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably using WinSCP to send or get files from/to the server, right? You might want to state that in your question. For that, you're probably better off with **FileZilla**. (You need the FileZilla *client*, not the Server)